# xmlhttp call with PHP

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I have the below PowerBuilder code that working fine and i want to create a similar process in PHP.
I am using xmlhttp and server replying with out any error.

```
ls_get_url = "https://staging.xxxxxx.com/acqapi/service.ashx"                       

data = "<CardInquiry>"
data += "<Cardholderid>9999999999999</Cardholderid>"
data += "</CardInquiry>"


ls_params_text = 'Username=LalakisAPI&Password='+ls_password+'&MessageId='+ls_messageID+'&ApiSignature=clear&Data='+data




            //First lets do a GET request 
            //All request parameters should be included in the URL
        loo_xmlhttp.open ("POST",ls_get_url, False)
        loo_xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )
        loo_xmlhttp.SetAutomationTimeOut(30000)
        try
                        loo_xmlhttp.send(ls_params_text)
        catch (RunTimeError ex1)

                         destroy loo_xmlhttp


                        Messagebox('RuntimeError',ex1.getmessage())
                        return
        end try


        //Get our response
        ls_status_text = loo_xmlhttp.StatusText
        ll_status_code =  loo_xmlhttp.Status
```